# Find how many characters a regex has looked at in a string before succeeding/failing

Tags: regex, rust

I want to see how many characters the regex has looked at before it succeeds or fails (to support incrementally re-lexing something). I haven't noticed a direct way to do this in the [Rust regex library's](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex) API.

If I could somehow intercept the `&str` I give to library, I could record the furthest character it's had to observe. I'm not sure how to do this, as I am new to Rust. If this were Java, I would use a proxy/implement `CharSequence`.

Bonus points if it works with [`RegexSet`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.1.0/regex/struct.RegexSet.html).

Comment: Please define what you mean by *character*. There are many possible meanings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Namely, it sounds like what you're asking is whether the regex crate supports incremental searching on streams. More specifically, whether you can use the regex crate to search text that does not necessarily live contiguously in memory.

In any case, the answer to both questions is: you can't, in general.

If you're curious about the complexities of supporting search on streams, [issue 425](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex/issues/425) tracks that feature.

Comment: I'm not really asking whether the regex crate supports incremental searching on streams - what really want is how far the regex matcher has had to search. The suggestion of intercepting `&str` is just one (possibly infeasible) solution for how to make that work, I'm open to other suggestions. At the limit, I suspect this could be done by forking the library myself and keeping track of the furthest char, but that sounds like a lot of work.

Comment: "how far the regex matcher has had to search" - The regex matcher might just decide to start from the end of the string.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: Honestly, that's fine/what I want for my usecase (but I suspect for most regexes that don't have a `$` in them it won't do that)

Comment: @CallumRogers This still seems to be an instance of the XY problem. What are you planning on doing with this information? Which characters looked at depends heavily on the regex engine implementation. For instance, some parts of the regex engine use SIMD instructions to match multiple bytes at a time with a single instruction. This may look further ahead in the string than you were expecting. Or it could do reverse search. And it can't be intercepted; the regex engine matches on raw byte sequences directly. With more information on your eventual goal, we may be able to provide an alternative.

Comment: @BrianCampbell: I'm going to use this information to try and do fast incremental re-lexing in an experimental lexer I'm writing. I don't think this is an instance of the XY problem because the question I'm not asking is "how do I write an incremental re-lexer" (that's way too big for SO!) it's "I'm experimenting with a way of incremental lexing, I need this specific feature from a library to try out to see if it works, how do I do it?".

Comment: @BrianCampbell: Also, this is a specific regex engine so I can work out exactly what it's going to do. It also doesn't work on raw bytes directly, it is abstracted over with [`Input`](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex/blob/d4b9419ed41907d5e8b43166ce7aef77e6fb93d9/src/input.rs#L81). I'm actually having some success with writing a `TrackingInout` that should do what I want in a forked version of the library.

Comment: Input is only used in the slower engines, so the result will not be fast, although you might consider it fast enough. The approach of forking and modifying the slower engines is exactly what I suggested in the linked issue. Regardless, your question is answered. You cannot do what you want with the regex crate as of today.

Comment: Note that I will be releasing a crate imminently that *may* make your use case substantially easier, depending on a few factors, without sacrficing speed. But I can't say for certain. (More specifically, it is a lower level regex library that exposes a more traditional finite automaton interface than what you typically find in a general purpose regex engine.)

Comment: @BurntSushi5: As to be expected, you're right - just realised `Input` is only used with the NFA engines. This is probably good enough for me (although is there a reason the DFA ones couldn't use a trait for getting bytes/slices from the text and recording the max value? Other than a likely perf hit?). The new crate sounds very interesting.

Comment: Am I right in thinking forward DFAs never backtrack? Then it looks like the `Result<usize>` will always return the furthest seen character. I can discount backwards searches being used as I won't accept `^` or `$` in my lexer.

Comment: @CallumRogers I am legitimately happy to answer specific questions, but please ask them on the issue tracker, ideally against something specific that has already been covered in my issue comments. Truthfully, questions like, "is there a reason why your specific implementation doesn't do X" in this context take a long time to answer, which is why I tried to dump all my thoughts on to the issue tracker so that I wouldn't need to continually go over this every time it comes up. :-)

Comment: A forward DFA never backtracks, yes. If you don't care about the start of a match---e.g., you are executing an anchored search---then the DFA can be made to report the end of a leftmost-first match in a single pass. This API is not exposed in the regex crate.

Comment: @BurntSushi5: thanks for your help, it has been appreciated! Looks like I can get this all working with a light fork of the crate.